# Bubble sort, selection sort, abstract classes (java)

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, bubble-sort, selection-sort

I've been reading up on Selection sort & Bubble sort as well abstract classes for like a week or so.  Despite searches on Google, YouTube, etc, I haven't been able to decipher a concrete difference between the two sorts because they seem very similar.

As far as abstract classes are concerned, I would like to know what you can & can't do with them.  For starters, you can't create an object of an abstract class type but that's about all I know, there has to be more to it.

I would appreciate it if someone can clear these this up for me.  Thanks :D.

Comment: these seem like two unrelated questions, please post them separately

Comment: Please [ask one question per post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 0):

Bubble and Selection sort are two of the most common sorting algorithms. Their main difference lies in the way these two perform the operation. Bubble algorithm iterates through the unsorted list comparing pairs of elements and checking if they are in order. The effect is that the larger(or smallest as per algorithm implementation) element moves to the end of list(or sorted list) or larger elements bubble over from unsorted to sorted list if you may. In selection sort however, algorithm chooses the largest(or smallest) element from unsorted list and adds to sorted list in each iteration, thus sorting the list. Main difference this 'pair-wise swapping' viz-a-viz 'selection'.
References:
[Efficiency of bubble sort vs selection sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440882/efficiency-of-bubble-vs-selection-sort)

As for second part: Correct. Abstract classes can't be instantiated. Abstract classes are mainly used in modelling for concrete classes as well as for use of dynamic polymorphism where you can refer to instances of two or more different subclasses(concrete) of a single class using abstract class variables.
References:
[What is an abstract class, and when should it be used?](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0084.html)